# Why app getting crash when It started Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc, When I start my Service?

Tags: android, service, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I'm Starting a `Service`(location service) at the beginning of app launch. But after staying on the App (approx. 5 to 10 minutes) I'm getting *`Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc`* error continuously and my app get stuck for a while then suddenly It crashes. 
Also, When I run the app without Service it works smoothly.

I've been searching for many days but nothing solved my problem. I checked many related Q/A over Stack overflow but there are not seems to be any proper or valuable answers.

I also tried by added `android:largeHeap="true"` in manifests and `multiDexEnabled true` but these didn't help even.

**Here's my Service class**

```
public class LocationService extends IntentService {

    private Context context;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task;

    public static String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.simpleapp",
            CHANNEL_NAME = "My Background Service";

    public LocationService() {
        super("LocationService");
    }
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            startMyOwnForeground();
        else startForeground(8, new Notification());

        createLocationRequest();


        context = this;
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);


        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(context);
        task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(@Nullable Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        try {
            fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper());
        } catch (SecurityException ignore) {
            Log.e("AppLocationService", "SecurityException - " + ignore.toString(), ignore);
        }


        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }


    private final LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            List<Location> locationList = locationResult.getLocations();
            if (locationList.size() != 0) {

                Location location = locationList.get(0);

                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();

                Intent intent = new Intent("location_update");
                intent.putExtra("latitude", lat);
                intent.putExtra("longitude", lng);
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        }
    };

 @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {


    }


    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(2000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(2000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(CommonObjects.LOCATION_PRIORITY);
    }
}
```

**My Logcat**

[image: Logcat Image]

Comment: Could you log all calls to `onStartCommand()` and `onLocationResult()` and re-post the logcat?

Comment: By putting all calls in `onStartCommand()` I'm still getting the same Logcat and behaviour!

Comment: What I was getting at is, how often is `onLocationResult()` being called?

Comment: `onLocationResult()` is being called only once.

Comment: Doesn't that strike you as a bit odd? Look, there's not much to see in your Service class. Why don't you go into a lot more detail about the changes you made that introduced the problem; add this code to your question. And it's probably a good time to start using the [heap dump button](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler#capture-heap-dump), to see what type of objects are causing your memory to fill up (which I assume is the case). You should also use the CPU profiler to see how much work your app is doing.